# Binding an string array to a DropDownList in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-binding, html.dropdownlistfor

Do you know how easily I can bind the contents of a string array to a DropDownList in view for MVC Razor?

```
public static string[] AgeRagne = new string[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed" };
```

UPDATE:
Below code worked.

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.Filter.AgeRange,
    new SelectList(Extensions.AgeRange, Model.Filter.AgeRange),
    new { @class = "search-dropdown", name = "ageRange" }
  )
```

Comment: I'm just taking a really wild guess .. but did you mean `AgeRange` not `AgeRagne`? =>=> `.. string[] AgeRagne = ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a not very nice but quick way would be to do this :):

```
<select name="dowList" id="dowList">
    @{string[] AgeRagne = new string[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed" };}
    @foreach (var dow in AgeRagne)
    {
        <option value="@dow">@dow</option>
    }
</select>
```

tho an htmlhelper would be the best long term stable solution.

Answer (score 28):

Create a `SelectList` with your array and pass it to your view:

```
SelectList list = new SelectList(AgeRagne);
ViewBag.myList = list;
```

Then in your view, use `Html.DropDownlist`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("myList", ViewBag.myList as SelectList)
```

That's all

Comment: quick and easy. one of the simplest ways to use a dropdownlist

Comment: One liner `@Html.DropDownList("myList", new SelectList(AgeRagne))`